# tjavaFlex Component Schema

Tags: talend

In my tjavaFlex Component Schema, I have set a default value("00") for a column ("RecordCode") in the "Default" column. I'm expecting that this value will take effect when a value is not assigned explicitly to the ("RecordCode") column. But it does not. When does the default value take effect?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [talend documentation](https://help.talend.com/r/SZ38A55h3ojQJL%7EpaOP16g/BVEYw8napmRe2IdVYBk4sw)

"At present, only tFileInputDelimited, tFileInputExcel, and tFixedFlowInput support default values in the schema."
Not sure they have planned to add support for this in the coming years...